# Interfacing MySQL and C

Tags: mysql, c, database, interface, cgi

I have OSX Lion, which comes with Postgres, but I'd rather us MySQL. But either way, I'm pretty lost. How would I go about interfacing C with MySQL, so I can just #include "mysql.h" (or maybe some other library) and go from there. Assume that all I've done so far is download the latest MySQL version.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you build and install mysql - it installed all headers and libraries when you do this.

Comment: No I haven't installed it yet. But I'm looking at the MySQL Connector/C and it seems like that might be what I need. What am I not getting from Connector/C that I would get with just the normal C API?

Comment: If you download mysql source - a build and install will give you everything you need to compile C applications to access mysql

Comment: Oh and if you can work with C++ they I personally recommend this library http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, just include the headers and link against the client libraries.  Documentation for the C API is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Connector/C (libmysql)?

Comment: Yes, Connector/C, libmysql is exactly what you can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-c-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience on iOS, but the basic steps apply to linux may be helpful to you.

1. Since you already have the latest MySQL version, then download the right manual from here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/
2. According to the manual chp.2, make and make install mysql on your computer.
3. After installing, you'll find include/mysql and lib/mysql directories under ($MYSQL_INSTALL_DIR), including mysql.h in your source file and linking appropriate .a file, then you can interfacing with MySQL(see manual Chp. APIs), maybe creating tables/insert/update etc.